# My CSS3 doesn't work in my html page

Tags: html, css

Im trying to use some CSS3 code to rotate my text but I think it doesn't get recognized?

**CSS code:**

```
.menu {
    background-image:url('button.jpg');
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 61px;
    height: 205px;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    writing-mode: rl-tb;
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<div id="menu-box">
    <a class="menu" href="#" >HOME</a>
    <a class="menu" href="#" >MYSELF</a>
    <a class="menu" href="#" >PORTFOLIO</a>
    <a class="menu" href="#" >CONTACT ME</a>        
</div>
```

Im not sure what the problem is. I am missing something?

Comment: On which browser its not working?

Comment: Btw, you are missing the unprefixed `transform`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't transform inline elements; change the display value of `.menu` to inline-block instead.

Simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/vg73f/

Comment: Im not so familiar with CSS3 yet. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

The `<a>` tags that your `.menu` class apply to are `inline` elements.  They need to be `block` level elements in order for the transform to apply.

By adding `display: block;` we can see that a transform applies correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/RvrBM/

Alternatively you could use `display: inline-block;` to allow the elements to rotate but stay in the inline arrangement.

http://jsfiddle.net/g5BRT/

Additionally, as Pavlo noted in the above comments, you are missing the unprefixed transform in your code.  It should look like this:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
-o-transform: rotate(270deg);
transform: rotate(270deg);
```